# TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int

Tags: python, cryptography, rainbowtable

i am trying to solve the `Rainbow Tables` issue with password encryption and have come only this far.

```
import sys
import random
import hashlib

def mt_rand (low = 0, high = sys.maxint):
    """Generate a better random value
    """
    return random.randint (low, high)

def substr (s, start, length = None):
    """Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length
    parameters.
    """
    if len(s) >= start:
        return False
    if not length:
        return s[start:]
    elif length > 0:
        return s[start:start + length]
    else:
        return s[start:length]

def unique_salt():
    return substr(hashlib.sha1(mt_rand()),0,22)

password = "12345"
salt = unique_salt()
hash = hashlib.sha1(salt + password).hexdigest()
print(hash)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ajay/PycharmProjects/itertools/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    salt = unique_salt()
  File "C:/Users/Ajay/PycharmProjects/itertools/test.py", line 24, in unique_salt
    return substr(hashlib.sha1(mt_rand()),0,22)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int
```

I know i am missing something very trivial but cant get where i am missing.
Please Help.

Comment: `hashlib.sha1` needs a string to be hashed, but you put an integer. What do you want to hash?

Comment: I want to hash password which is a `string`.

Comment: And what's the `unique_salt` function for?

Comment: @aIKid I want to generate a random string for each user and use that as the unique salt.

Comment: Relevant article: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: You're doing it wrong. 1) You RNG is too weak. Use `SystemRandom` instead 2) You're using a general purpose crypto hash (SHA-1, SHA-2, etc.) instead of a specialized password hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`hashlib.sha1`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) accepts a string as a parameter.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha1('asdf')
<sha1 HASH object @ 0000000002B97DF0>
```

But you're passing a int object. (The return value of the `random.randint` is `int` object as the name suggest)

```
>>> hashlib.sha1(1234)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int
```

You can use [`os.urandom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom) to generate random string:

```
>>> import os
>>> hashlib.sha1(os.urandom(10)) # `os.urandom(10)` generate 10-bytes random string.
<sha1 HASH object @ 0000000002B97F30>
>>> hashlib.sha1(os.urandom(10)).digest()
'\x0c.y\x08\x13\xf0\x16.\xea\x05\x03\x07{6H\xa0U\xfe\xdfT'
>>> hashlib.sha1(os.urandom(10)).hexdigest()
'6e33d9cfdbd7ffcf062ee502eaa25893f618fcff'
```

Comment: @ajkumar25, `def unique_salt(): return hashlib.sha1(os.urandom())[:22]`

Comment: `def unique_salt(): return hashlib.sha1(os.urandom()).hexdigest()[:22]`

Comment: @ajkumar25, Oh, you're right. I missed `digest`/`hexdigest` in the above comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use python's built-in function `type` to inspect objects.

```
>>>type(mt_rand())
int
>>>hashlib.sha1(mt_rand())
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int
```

This is to be expected.  Pass hashlib.sha1 a string instead.

```
>>>hashlib.sha1("password")
<sha1 HASH object @ 0x1c89cb0>
```

Answer (score 2):

`hashlib.sha1` needs a string to be hashed, but you put an integer.

Convert it to string first:

```
def unique_salt():
    return substr(hashlib.sha1(str(mt_rand())),0,22)
```

Here's a bit of demo:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import random
>>> s = random.randint(1, 1000)
>>> hashlib.sha1(str(s)).digest()
'\xd1\x84\x01\xb1\xbb7\xc5\xd9)|\xf1o\xc48X\xb4\xfd\xb3x%'
```